# How to resolve class file for com.google.cloud.Service not found

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am Trying to upload JSON data to gcs. As I did not use google cloud previously I started with uploading random String to gcs but I got stuck at the beginning itself while creating a Storage service object

Maven dependency

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
   <version>1.70.0</version>
 </dependency>


import com.google.cloud.storage.*;
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("bucket_name", "test_upload/test.txt");
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
    Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, "Hello, Cloud Storage!".getBytes(UTF_8));
    System.out.println(blob);
```

Compile Time Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project gcshelper: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
ERROR] /Users/v3/gcshelper/src/main/java/com/tv/gcs/GcsTest.java:[16,41] cannot access com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions [ERROR] class file for com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions not found [ERROR] /Users/v3/gcshelper/src/main/java/com/tv/gcs/GcsTest.java:[19,28] cannot access com.google.cloud.Service [ERROR] class file for com.google.cloud.Service not found [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: If you could post a test sample where it can be downloaded (a zip, tar or github), I for one would be happy to try on my system.

Answer (score 4):

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>google-cloud</artifactId>
 <version>0.47.0-alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

If someone is using `module-info.java` then you need to have these two dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.21</version>
    </dependency>
```

and in your `module-info.java` do something like:

```
open module ModuleName {
    ...
    requires google.cloud.core;
    requires google.cloud.firestore;
    requires com.google.auth;
    requires com.google.auth.oauth2;
    ...
}
```

if you are using intellij, then it will ask you to do `google.cloud.firestore` and `com.google.auth.oauth2` but this won't work as these depend on `google.cloud.core` and `com.google.auth`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to include this dependency in your pom.xml ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.70.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am getting below error after adding the above dependency:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/auth/Credentials
 at com.tv.gcs.GcsTest.main(GcsTest.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.auth.Credentials
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 1 more

Comment: Looks like you may need to add ... https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java

Comment: adding the dependency mentioned by @Kolban is not working, same issue exists

Comment: If you wish, upload a ZIP, tar or point to a Github of a sample trivial failing project with instructions on how you build and I for one will be willing to have a test.

Comment: if I go on adding the dependency the dependencies are increasing.

Comment: @Kolban there is nothing extra code, it's just as is I uploaded the code content. If you want to recreate the same on your machine create a class file and paste above code should be fine

Comment: Howdy ... I understand.  When ever I am looking for help on StackOverflow, I try and make it ridiculously easy for others to assist me.  If I have a problem with simple code or execution, I try and build the most minimal sample that illustrates the problem and then give that to the readers to run.  I don't want to make folks who may be able to assist do any more work than necessary ... such as creating wrapper classes or POM files.  I also include full instructions to recreate.  It is also common that my own error shines through in the full sample code.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EMpS6D3iYWJjqnneO6GqceNor2m41ZpF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I downloaded and ran your ZIP using "mvn compile" and I got 100% success for a clean build.  Now we get to execution.  Exactly, how are you running your application?  My guess is that when you run it, you have not supplied the classes to the Class Path that are part of the Google Cloud SDK.

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is that you can’t upload files to the gcp container using java, and the stack trace is showing that maven failing at compilation time.

Well, You can try 2 things:

1.- Make sure that you Authentication settings are good, You can follow the steps in the link[1].
2.- Configure you Maven installation according the gcp instructions[2].

[1]https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-java
[2]https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven#setting_up_maven