# how to export a javafx-maven project with firebase

Tags: java, firebase, maven, javafx, jlink

for now i have got my project to run on `mvn javafx:run`. but a module descriptor is required to execute `mvn javaFx:jlink`. there are some firebase related errors after creating the module info file.

some of the imports imports :

```
import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.*;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
```

requires in the module info file :

```
requires com.google.api.apicommon;
requires com.google.auth.oauth2;
requires firebase.admin;
requires google.cloud.firestore;
```

errors :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:run (default-cli) on project RathnapuraLabs: Error: Unable to execute mojo: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Eshaka/IdeaProjects/RathnapuraLabs/src/main/java/back_end/TestManager.java:[14,35] cannot access com.google.cloud.Service
[ERROR]   class file for com.google.cloud.Service not found
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Eshaka/IdeaProjects/RathnapuraLabs/src/main/java/back_end/DBHandler.java:[69,33] cannot access com.google.auth.Credentials
[ERROR]   class file for com.google.auth.Credentials not found
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Eshaka/IdeaProjects/RathnapuraLabs/src/main/java/back_end/DBHandler.java:[100,85] cannot access com.google.cloud.Timestamp
[ERROR]   class file for com.google.cloud.Timestamp not found
```

how can i fix this error?

Comment: Please add a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a much easier way to export all the dependencies and all (firebase included). just use the `maven-shape-plugin` to package.

1. Add the following plugin to the pom.xml

   ```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>Launcher</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
   ```
2. You need to create another class with a main that calls the main function of the main javafx class that extends the application as below.

   ```
    public class Launcher {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            AppInit.main(args);
        }
    }
   ```
3. finally run `mvn clean package`

Answer (score 0):

I did face a similar issue before, this indicates that you are missing a few dependencies in your pom.xml:

```
[ERROR]   class file for com.google.cloud.Service not found
[ERROR]   class file for com.google.auth.Credentials not found
[ERROR]   class file for com.google.cloud.Timestamp not found
```

Make sure you included them. You can see a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833935/how-to-resolve-class-file-for-com-google-cloud-service-not-found).
Make sure you resolve all conflicts after including the dependencies, or you'll get:

> Module 'com.example' reads package 'package' from both 'package.example' and 'package.example'